# How can I change the status of Trigger MetaData using Apex Programming(Tooling/MetaData API)

Tags: trigger, metadata-api

I am using this code to update metadata for trigger.

```
public void createMetadataContainer()
{
        HttpRequest req = createHttpRequest(endpoint+'/MetadataContainer','POST');
        req.setBody('{"Name":"ApexContainer"}');
        String response = getResponse(req);
        System.debug('response'+response);
        Map<String,Object> rmp = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(response);
        String cid = (String)rmp.get('id'); // used to save containerId

        updateApexTriggerMember(cid , '01q20000000PC2X');


}

    // mid: MetadaContainserId
    // axid: apexclass Id
    // classBody: Apex class body (updated)
    public void updateApexTriggerMember(String mid, String axid)
    {
        HttpRequest req = createHttpRequest(endpoint+'/ApexTriggerMember','POST');
        req.setBody('{"MetadataContainerId" : "'+mid+'", "ContentEntityId" : "'+axid+'", "Metadata": { "Status": "Inactive"} }');
        String response = getResponse(req);
        System.debug('response'+response);
        Map<String,Object> rmp = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(response);
        String apmid = (String)rmp.get('id'); 
    }
```

Response that I get is response

> [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of complexvalue from
>   VALUE_STRING value Inactive or request may be missing a required field
>   at [line:1, column:112]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]

Comment: Can you post sample response as well?

Answer (score 2):

You simply have a capitalization error in your `Metadata` body. The key `Status` should be `status`. Here's an example I executed in Workbench REST Explorer:

> /services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Metadata+FROM+ApexTrigger+WHERE+name+=+'AccountsTrigger'

yields

```
{
    "MetadataContainerId":"1dc1K0000011mbPQAQ",
    "ContentEntityId": "01q41000001d3z6AAA",
    "Metadata": { 
        "status": "Inactive"
    } 
}
```

Note the capitalization.

Then, POST to

> /services/data/v43.0/tooling/sobjects/MetadataContainer

to get a container Id, and POST to

> /services/data/v43.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexTriggerMember

```
{
    "MetadataContainerId":"1dc1K0000011mbPQAQ",
    "ContentEntityId": "01q41000001d3z6AAA",
    "Metadata": { 
        "status": "Inactive"
    } 
}
```

This returns successfully. Posting the exact same request body with `Status` in upper case replicates the error you observe.